# File Upload into Azure Data Lake Storage

Tags: node.js, azure

I am new to Node and need to write a Node js app to upload a bunch of files into Azure Data Lake store, The file size is in MB can go into GB, what would be the best way to do it , any node package which can help with the same ? Any pointers highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@azure/storage-file-datalake`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-file-datalake) package to interact with Azure Data Lake Storage. You can find some samples for interacting with it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-javascript.

Code sample for uploading a file from the [`same link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-javascript#upload-a-file-to-a-directory):

```
async function UploadFile(fileSystemClient) {

  const fs = require('fs') 

  var content = "";

  fs.readFile('mytestfile.txt', (err, data) => { 
      if (err) throw err; 

      content = data.toString();

  }) 

  const fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("my-directory/uploaded-file.txt");
  await fileClient.create();
  await fileClient.append(content, 0, content.length);
  await fileClient.flush(content.length);

}
```